# Quick question about sequelize migrations

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

I'm trying to do sequelize migrations on the models I created such as User.js, Blogs.js etc... What I've noticed is that I can add columns to Models like User.js and Blogs.js, but if I dont change the files in my models folder, the changes will be recognized in the database, but I wont be able to access the new columns when the server is running.

EG:

I add column permission: {type: Sequelize.STRING} to User.js.

I can't access this column because my original model file doesn't contain permission. Do I have to delete the models, and then create them using the sequelize-cli in order to get the migrations to also update the model files?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear.

In order to add a new column to a table using Sequelize migrations, you need to do the following steps:

1. Generate a new migration file.
2. Using queryInterface methods, make the changes to your tables in the migration file.
3. Execute your migrations.
4. Update your models with any new properties that are added.
5. Restart your server.

Keep in mind that migrations are done as an ALTERNATIVE to using the sequelize.sync() method. If you are using the sync() method, you cannot add columns to a table without using the { force: true } flag inside of sync(), which causes your tables to be dropped and data lost. Migrations are a process that requires a bit more attention to be paid, but they are a feasible long-term solution for a production database.